# Bundles in MVC4 working incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am attempting to modify the CSS Bundle within the `BundleConfig` class but for some reason the `font-awesome.min.css` file is never sent to the browser, only site.css is sent.

Here is how I include the bundle within my layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

And here is how I define it

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css"
    ));
```

Note that the file im adding is in the same location as site.css within the `Content` folder. Also: site.css is only included within that bundle and no where else within the entire project

Comment: What is the rendered result of this in the page source?

Comment: The only stylesheet sent is `site.css` which is exactly as it is in the source (i.e. not minified or altered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because your css file has ".min" in the name and you're running in Debug mode. Try to rename it or include it in the ignore list of the bundling.

*Note:* If you have the non ".min" version and use it during development after switching to release the engine will use the `.min` version.

If you use this during development:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/font-awesome.css"
));
```

When you switch to Release the minification engine will look for corresponding `.min` files and use them accordingly, otherwise it will minify them for you.